# Slider step rate based on speed of moving the slider

Tags: c#, xaml, slider, winrt-xaml

I have a UWP XAML app that is using a slider as a volume control for a piece of audio hardware on the network. My issue is there is a 50ms+ required delay between sending volume changes, so if I quickly move the slider from minimum to maximum, it takes the hardware a few seconds to catch up as the app is sending a new +1 level each valuechanged event of the slider.

I don't want to change the step of the slider because I want precise control as well. Smallstep/largestep don't really help. Is there built-in functionality that will change the step based on the velocity you're moving the slider, i.e. slow movement, step =1, medium movement step =5, fast movement step= 10?

If not, does anyone have any suggestions on how this can be implemented? I think I can do something with the manipulation events.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way you can change the slider's step based on drag velocity. 
You have to subscribe to the `ManipulationDelta` event (don't forget to set the `ManipulationMode` of the slider to something other than System or None).
Then in the handler get the `Velocities` from the `ManipulationDeltaRoutedEventArgs` arguments. Something like that

```
public void MySlider_ManipulationDelta(object sender, 
  ManipulationDeltaRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var velocities = e.Velocities
    var slider = sender as Slider;
    if(slider != null)
    {
        //Create a fomula based on the velocities to fit your needs.
    }

}
```

You should also remember to reset the step of the slider on the ManipulationCompleted event.

Having said that, I don't see how changing the step based on drag velocity would help you achieve the desired result. From my understanding, due to parameters outside your control (network, hardware etc), there is a 50ms delay between the time your app sends data and the time the hardware reflects the change. And that's that.

Comment: I was thinking I'd need to do something like this, hoping there was something built it. I can set the volume to any number I want. If you quickly move the slide from 1 to 100 now, it has the send 100 volume change commands because valuechanged fires 100 times... 1,2,3,4,5,6,8,9,10, etc... But if I base it on velocity, and the steps go up to 10, I could send only 10 volume commands: 10, 20, 30, etc